# Какой алгоритм сортировки используется в MySQL при ORDER BY?

Tags: сортировка, mysql

Интересно, какая вычислительная сложность алгоритма, который лежит в основе сортировки в мускуле?

Comment: Вопрос не корректный, т.к. в MySQL не один алгоритм сортировки.

Comment: @razielsd в смысле "их нет" или "их очень много" ?

Comment: @stalinz, в смысле "много".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не конкретный ответ на вопрос. но всё же:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

```
MySQL has two filesort algorithms for sorting and retrieving results.
```

И т.д. по тексту

Comment: Судя по описанию алгоритмов в ссылке из ответа, если парой слов, то используется сортировка многопутевым слиянием с внешней памятью.